# Quantum decoherence revisited

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence

I asked a question about whether decoherence is dependent and received some helpful replies (thanks!). I tried to leave a comment detailing the article I was reading, but it was too long to be accepted, so below is what prompted my question. Does what follows have any merit?

> "Quantum states are mathematically considered to be vectors in a Hilbert space. To represent a vector, one needs to choose a set of orthogonal basis vectors. But such a choice is arbitrary, as long as it is a complete set. This is like choosing any three arbitrary orthogonal directions in an Euclidean space to be x, y, and z axes. A superposition state in one basis may
>   not be a superposition in another basis. For example, a|0> + b|1> is a superposition in the computation basis (made of |0> & |1>), but it is not a superposition in a basis made of orthogonal states |xi = a|0> + b|1> and |y> = b∗|0> − a∗|1>.
>   This makes the above definition of decoherence kind of confused, because it is clearly basis dependent. In other words, if decoherence destroys superposition in one basis it may not destroy it in another basis. For example, suppose the
>   environment destroys superposition only in the above xy basis. Any superposition state like α|x> + β|y>, therefore, will be destroyed after the decoherence time, thus, the system will end up in a mixed state. State |x> itself is not a superposition in this basis, therefore will not be affected by such a deconerence. It is, however, a superposition in the computation basis by definition. Such a superposition, therefore, will be unaffected by this decoherence effect.
>   It is therefore not correct to assume all superpositions are destroyed after the decoherence time. One needs to clearly specify in what basis the environment acts and what is its influence in other bases."

Comment: Can you provide a source for this article? Its context might be important.

Comment: Have to confess I don't know where the article came from - and can't now find it again!

Comment: Link to the other question?